# How to make folder in my project folder in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make a folder `upload` in this path `projectname/app/assets/upload` and I am using below:

```
directory_name = "upload"
    Dir.mkdir(directory_name) unless File.exists?(directory_name)
```

but it creates folder in the project `projectname/upload`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Rails.root`](http://apidock.com/rails/Rails/root/class) will return a `Pathname` to the root directory of your Rails app. You can use [`Pathname#join`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-join) to append items to the path.

```
path = Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "upload");
Dir.mkdir(path) unless File.exist?(path)
```